# Hotlinking images hosted in my server

Tags: image, html-email, hotlinking

I uploaded a template with jpg images in an auction site. The images are hosted in my server. The problem is that these images are displayed in google images.

I configured hotlink for the images, with exceptions to the auction site domain.

But the problem is when I try to send an email to anyone, like gmail, live, icloud, etc. the images not shown.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Well, that's exactly what you've restricted. You could do one of two things: Also exclude the email-websites or embed the images in the emails.

Comment: I tryed with embed using base64 but gmail doesn't shown the image and I don't know which email-websites address belong to gmail, yahoo, live, etc.

Comment: You have add the image as an attachment, not directly in the HTML. Embedding the image directly in HTML won't work in all email clients.